# Permission error in load_dataset() from datasets library

Tags: python, nlp, dataset, permissionerror

I'm trying to get Wikisql dataset using the following code snippet.

```
from datasets import load_dataset
import random, warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

valid_dataset = load_dataset('wikisql', split='validation')

valid_dataset[0]
```

But it throws following error. I am not the administrator, but this error occurs in certain datasets only.

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\.cache\\huggingface\\datasets\\wiki_sql\\default\\0.1.0\\2e98053891fd8f9b2c4348bba609ce40cc0a4d7f621191cebcd7cb558b5f8a70.incomplete' -> 'C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\.cache\\huggingface\\datasets\\wiki_sql\\default\\0.1.0\\2e98053891fd8f9b2c4348bba609ce40cc0a4d7f621191cebcd7cb558b5f8a70'
```

As this appeared to be permission error in C drive, tried changing the cache directory, but still same error coming from that location.

```
dataset = load_dataset('wikisql', split='validation', cache_dir="PATH/TO/MY/CACHE/DIR")
```

Any help would be highly appriciated.
I am using datasets==1.4.1